# Python, PIL; Text to Image and insertion into MS Excel

Tags: python, image, excel, python-imaging-library, antialiasing

I'm using Python and PIL to create "Text to Image" figures and place these into MS Excel documents. I'm having issues with image quality -

So far I'm able to create images from given text, though once inserted into Excel I see quality is bad - image below shows "Text box" within Excel {Top}, and insertion of an image into Excel {bottom} - I thought `draw.fontmode = "1"` would help as it activates anti-aliasing but this doesn't look successful **once** the image is inserted into Excel.

Suggestions welcome. 
[image]

Code I'm using so far:

```
import PIL
from PIL import ImageFont
from PIL import Image
from PIL import ImageDraw

fontBold      = ImageFont.truetype("Arialbd.ttf",18)
font          = ImageFont.truetype("Arial.ttf",  14)
img           = Image.new("RGBA", (570,200),(255,255,255))
draw          = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
line0         = "Title Here"
line1         = "Some blurb here under title - main text here, fontmode='1'"
draw.fontmode = "1"
draw.text((180,30),  line0,(0,0,0),font=fontBold)
draw.text((0,  60),  line1,(0,0,0),font=font)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img)
img.save("a_test_fontmode1.png", quality=100)
```